# Materialize fixed header and scroll, issue with footer and mobile

Tags: css, materialize, infinite-scroll, fixed-header-tables

I have the following materialize table:

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
         <div id="table" class="card card card-default scrollspy">
             <div class="card-content  material-table ">
                 <h4 class="card-title">Users Live Results</h4>

                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col s12"></div>

                     <div class="col s12">
                         <table class="responsive-table striped">
                             <thead>
                                 <tr>
                                     <th style="text-align:left;">User</th>

                                     <th style="text-align:right;">RM Deposits</th>

                                     <th style="text-align:right;">RM+RB GGR</th>

                                     <th style="text-align:right;">RM Win</th>

                                     <th style="text-align:right;">RB Win</th>

                                     <th style="text-align:right;">PB Win</th>

                                     <th style="text-align:right;">RM&RB Balance</th>

                                     <th style="text-align:right;">Bo Deposits</th>

                                     <th style="text-align:right;">Withdrawals</th>
                                 </tr>
                             </thead>

                             <tbody>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td style="text-align:left;">Moha</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">140</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">140</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">140</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">140</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>
                                 </tr>

                                 <tr>
                                     <td style="text-align:left;">handx</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">99</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">99</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">151</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">250</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>
                                 </tr>

                                 <tr>
                                     <td style="text-align:left;">Arff</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">19</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">19</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">106</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">13</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>
                                 </tr>


                             </tbody>

                             <tfoot>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>Total</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">140</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">260</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">161</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">99</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">257</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;"></td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">250</td>

                                     <td style="text-align:right;">0</td>
                                 </tr>
                             </tfoot>
                         </table>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I used a CSS fixed header and scroll for tables with a lot of data with the following css:

```
table {
    font-size: 12px;
}

tbody {
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}
table {
    width:100%;
}
```

It is working but the footer of the table is outside of the scroll section (offset)

as per this screenshot:

[image]

Finally, on small devices, the scroll does not work at all, so I should exclude the CSS for smaller devices and I did not find any solution to do so.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score -1):

You have too much CSS in the table which offset's the natural CSS that is there. You can add padding to the td tag to set up how you want it to be spaced.

You can play with the different heights you need ( the table or content is set to whatever height and same for the parent container to make sure it scrolls ).

```
table {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 500px;
}
tbody {
    overflow:auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
    table-layout:fixed;
}
thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}
.SetContainer{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/86rnu03L/1/

Comment: with this proposed CSS, I lose the scroll and height capability I had, I need the table to have a fixed header and to be scrollable